# cumulative month to date and year to date sum

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am having issues finding a solution for the cummulative sum for mtd and ytd

I need help to get this result

[image: Final result]

Comment: What code have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) combined with periods using [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
# ensure datetime
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False)
# group by year
df['ytd'] = df.groupby(s.dt.to_period('Y'))['count'].cumsum()
# group by month
df['mtd'] = df.groupby(s.dt.to_period('M'))['count'].cumsum()
```

Example (with dummy data):

```
         date  count  ytd  mtd
0  2022-08-26      6    6    6
1  2022-08-27      1    7    7
2  2022-08-28      4   11   11
3  2022-08-29      4   15   15
4  2022-08-30      8   23   23
5  2022-08-31      4   27   27
6  2022-09-01      6   33    6
7  2022-09-02      3   36    9
8  2022-09-03      5   41   14
9  2022-09-04      8   49   22
10 2022-09-05      7   56   29
11 2022-09-06      9   65   38
12 2022-09-07      9   74   47
```